# How to find elements by which 2 elements of $S_n$ are conjugate to each other?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

I had come across to one theorem which says
 $\pi$=$\sigma (i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4..,,i_k)\sigma ^{-1}$ 
 where $\pi$=($\sigma(i_1),\sigma(i_2),\sigma(i_3),\sigma(i_4))......,\sigma(i_k)$ )
$\pi$$\sigma(i_1)$=$\sigma (i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4..,,i_k)\sigma ^{-1}$ $\sigma(i_1)$=$\sigma(i_2)$.Upto This I understand Now to use this theorem Here

Given Permutation x=(1,2)(3,4) and y=(5,6)(1,3).
I wanted to find 'a' such that $axa^{-1}$=y.
$axa^{-1}$(a(1))=a(2)=y(a(1)) Here is confusion what is a(1) now here ?
How to use that proof to come to answer .

Sub question : I know that 2 elements that are not of equal cycle type are not conjugate to each other .But is this argument is enough to show that following 
Prove that there is no a such that $a^{-1}(1,2,3)a$=(1,3),(5,7,8) .
Or there exist some proof that I have to give for this problem.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I am not really sure what the "such that $xa = ay$" part is supposed to mean here. Could you clarify that?

Comment: problem had been edited Sir.@ Tobias Kildetoft

Comment: The way to find an $a$ that works is that you should hopefully have been shown a formula for what happens when you conjugate a cycle by some element.

Comment: Sorry Sir ,but Still I am not getting

Comment: Hopefully, whatever book this is from should have a formula for what happens when you conjugate a cycle by an arbitrary permutation? Does it have such a formula?

Comment: I am following Herstein Book Which according to me have no such formula .I had come across one pdf Where such formula is present .I wanted to understand how that formula come across.can you help me ?

Comment: try to write a cycle decomposition of $a^{-1}xa$ by considering where it maps $1^a$, $2^a$ and so on (or $a^{-1}(1)$, $a^{-1}(2)$ and so on if you have permutations act on the left).

Comment: Here I had one problem There are 2 cycle of same length which  cycle I associate to particular one.

Answer (score 1):

Line up the permutations by their cycle length; stacking them on top of each other. Then, let $a$ be the permutation that sends the corresponding numbers to each other.

So in this case we have $$(1\ 2)(3\ 4)(5)(6),$$ $$(5\ 6)(1\ 3)(2)(4).$$ So $$a=(1\ 5\ 2\ 6\ 4\ 3).$$

Comment: I wanted to know intuition Sir please can you explained? .Also Here order of cycle even though disjoint why so important ? Why (5,6)(1,3) are we have to take in same order Why not reverse order ?

Comment: You can take them in either order. It doesn't matter. If you take them in order $(13)(56)(4)(2)$, you get $a = (2\,3\,5\,4\,6)$, which also works. The answer is not unique.

Comment: Sir I can now find any such elements Still I wanted to know how can by this process we obtain a? What is intuition behind that.